# How to complete this if statement

Tags: if-statement

If `user_tickets` is less than `5`, assign `1` to `num_tickets`. Else, assign `user_tickets` to `num_tickets`.

Sample output with input: 3

Value of `num_tickets`: 1

```
user_tickets = int(input())

if user_tickets < 5:
   num_tickets = 1
  else: 
    user_tickets = num_tickets
    
print('Value of num_tickets:', num_tickets)
```

Comment: Does "assign `user_tickets` to `num_tickets`" and `user_tickets = num_tickets` look to be the same?

Comment: yes these are still the same. I only need to write 1 expression

Comment: They are not the same. Look at your code again.

Comment: yes I figured it out. you were right

Answer (score 0):

Here what you need to do:

```
user_tickets = int(input())
num_tickets = 0 #define num_tickets
if user_tickets < 5:
    num_tickets = 1
else:
    num_tickets = user_tickets #assining user_tickets to num_tickets

print('Value of num_tickets:', num_tickets)
```